# Google's App Engine: Streamlit WebRTC's player with sendrecv mode serves only one request at a time

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, webrtc, streamlit

I have a website built with Streamlit, hosted on Google's App Engine. Using streamlit_webRTC I implemented a streamer that reads image from visitor's camera, feeds it to my algorithm (face detection, mask on/off classification) and returns the processed image to the player.

```
WEBRTC_CLIENT_SETTINGS = ClientSettings(
    rtc_configuration={"iceServers": [{"urls": ["stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"]}]},
    media_stream_constraints={"video": True, "audio": False},
)
```

```
def app_mask_detection():

    class OpenCVVideoTransformer(VideoTransformerBase):
        def __init__(self) -> None:
            self.assembly = ModelAssembly()    

        def transform(self, frame: av.VideoFrame) -> av.VideoFrame:
            img = frame.to_ndarray(format="bgr24")
           
            return self.assembly.forwardFrame(img)

    webrtc_ctx = webrtc_streamer(
        key="opencv-filter",
        mode=WebRtcMode.SENDRECV,
        client_settings=WEBRTC_CLIENT_SETTINGS,
        video_transformer_factory=OpenCVVideoTransformer,
        async_transform=True,
    )
```

The issue is that only one visitor at a time can use the streamer.
It seems to me that the active instance is getting clogged until the visitor closes the streamer. Two possible solutions I see:

a) Modify App Engine settings to create a separate instance per visitor.

b) Modify some sort of streamer's settings in the code.

Even if these solutions were valid, I am completely clueless where to look for how-to's, that's why I am writing this post. Any pointers will be highly appreciated.

Comment: 0.9.0 release of streamlit_webrtc fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments OP found the solution:

> 0.9.0 release of `streamlit_webrtc` fixed the issue.

If you have a similar issue, please consider upgrading to the version 0.9.0 or higher.